# Limit with factorials

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like to compute this limit
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}.$$

I know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}=1$ but I do not have any idea how to compute this manually. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to $n!$ for large $n$

Comment: You can also notice that 
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{
\Gamma^2(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{\Gamma(2n+2)}{
\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{1}{B(n+1;n+1)}$$
Using the integral representation of Beta-function
$$B(n+1;n+1)=\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^ndx\overset{x=t+\frac{1}{2}}{=}\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\Big)^ndt=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}e^{n\ln(1-4t^2)}dt$$
The asymptotic of the integral via Laplace method is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Stirling formula: $n! \sim \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$ as $n \to +\infty$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} \sim \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}  \left(\dfrac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\frac{2 \pi n}{2^{2n}2 \pi n}\bigg(\dfrac{e}{n}\bigg)^{2n}=1$$

Comment: This limit is often used to obtain the constant $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in Stirling's formula. For that reason I would use the Wallis integrals instead.